# SQL Python user specified query

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have the following SQL statement to select the monthly sales of each product stored in my database. The product is selected based upon the user input. The query works for this table.

```
+------------+----------+-------+-------+-----------+
| orderDate  | Espresso | Latte | Mocha | Cappucino |
+------------+----------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 2019-01-01 |       18 |    20 |    10 |        12 |
| 2019-01-02 |       13 |    11 |    20 |        10 |
| 2019-01-03 |       12 |    14 |    13 |        14 |
| 2019-01-04 |       20 |    13 |    15 |        14 |
| 2019-01-05 |       17 |    18 |    11 |        16 |
+------------+----------+-------+-------+-----------+


import sqlite3
title = input("Enter column to search")

sql = """SELECT SUM(sub.sales) as total_sales,
                strftime("%m-%Y", sub.[orderDate]) as 'month-year'
         FROM
              (SELECT [orderDate], Espresso AS sales, 'Espresso' as item
               FROM groupedSales
               UNION ALL
               SELECT [orderDate], Latte AS sales, 'Latte' as item
               FROM groupedSales
               UNION ALL
               SELECT [orderDate], Mocha AS sales, 'Mocha' as item
               FROM groupedSales
               UNION ALL
               SELECT [orderDate], Cappucino AS sales, 'Cappucino' as item
               FROM groupedSales
               UNION ALL
               SELECT [orderDate], Americano AS sales, 'Americano' as item
               FROM groupedSales
               UNION ALL 
              ) AS sub
         WHERE sub.[item] = ? AND milkOptions = 'Soya'
         GROUP BY strftime("%m-%Y", sub.[orderDate])
     """

conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
aggregateIndividuals = cur.execute(sql, (title, milkOptions,)).fetchall()

valueArray = []
valueArray2 = []
for values in aggregateIndividuals:
    print(values)
```

Here is a typical output:

Enter column to searchEspresso

(494, '01-2019')

(440, '02-2019')

(447, '03-2019')

(447, '04-2019')

(452, '05-2019')

(439, '06-2019')

(433, '07-2019')

(482, '08-2019')

(443, '09-2019')

(440, '10-2019')

(441, '11-2019')

(458, '12-2019')

However, the table above was test data and does not represent the format of my actual table that feeds in customer orders. How would I adapt the query to select the monthly sales of each product from the new table, given there are no product headings but instead cells of the product name under the column product.
Here is my actual table which I would like to use this query on:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
| orderid |  product  |  size  | milkOptions | orderDate  | quantity | price | customerid |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
|       1 | Espresso  | Small  | Soya        | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |          1 |
|       2 | Cappucino | Small  | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |          1 |
|       3 | Cappucino | Small  | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |          1 |
|       4 | Cappucino | Medium | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |          1 |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

I am using DB Browser for SQlite3. TO NOTE: I have cut down the records on both databases to minimally reproduce this, but there is a record for every day of the year in the orderDate column in my actual browser and there are more examples of different products ordered in my second table, but i have cut it down for this example.

Comment: First take a look at [mcve]. Then add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Hi, I have made edits to the post. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query could be so much simpler than the showed one. For example, if you need to get the results for "Cappucino" you can just:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
| orderid |  product  |  size  | milkOptions | orderDate  | quantity | price | customerid |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+
|       1 | Espresso  | Small  | Soya        | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
|       2 | Cappucino | Small  | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
|       3 | Cappucino | Small  | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
|       4 | Cappucino | Medium | SemiSkimmed | 2019-10-29 |        1 | 1.0   |        1   |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+------------+

select sum(quantity*price), strftime("%m-%Y", orderDate) as month 
from coffee
where product = 'Cappucino'
group by product, month

+---------+-----------+
|  sales  |   month   |
+---------+-----------+
|       3 |  10-2019  |
|       2 |  11-2019  |
|       2 |  12-2019  |
+---------+-----------+
```

Obviously you need to make the 'Cappucino' parametrized to accept any possible product, that will be inserted from the standard input (input() command in Python), and the filtering clause can be certainly modified according to your needs. Anyway i created a demonstration on SQLFiddle that you can see and try [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d4d83/4)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for an aggregation query?

```
select orderdate, product, sum(quantity * price) as total_sales
from t
group by orderdate
order by orderdate;
```